# How to do a iloc slice on a multi-index DataFrame while keeping original file order?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a DataFrame that is looking like this (using .to_markdown() which is showing the 3 index columns as one) :

|  | id | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (2022, 'may', 27) | LB46 | 10 | 12 |
| (2022, 'may', 28) | LB46 | 10 | 12 |
| (2022, 'may', 29) | LB46 | 10 | 12 |
| (2022, 'may', 30) | LB46 | 10 | 12 |
| (2022, 'may', 31) | LB46 | 40 | 12 |
| (2022, 'june', 1) | LB46 | 50 | 12 |
| (2022, 'june', 2) | LB46 | 90 | 12 |
| (2022, 'june', 3) | LB46 | 110 | 12 |

An other preview using .head() :

[image]

This is a multi-index Dataframe with 3 index which here are "year", "month" and "day". These index are arbitrary choose for the example, it could be any kind of index. Then I can't rely on date conversion, I want to rely on original order which is the one shown.

But I also want to do a slice between the line (2022, 'may', 29) and (2022, 'june', 1).

To do that I try to use DataFrame.loc :

```
    df= df.loc[('2022','may','29'): ('2022', 'june', '1')]
```

But it leads to this error :

> pandas.errors.UnsortedIndexError: 'Key length (3) was greater than
> MultiIndex lexsort depth (1)'

So then I tried to get my DataFrame sorted using  :

```
df_csv.sort_index(Inplace=True)
```

The problem with that is that whatever options of sort_index I use, the order of my DataFrame kept altered (as for example there are no possibility to choose an order other than ascending or descending). Again I don't know the comparison function to use for the sort, so what I really want it to have it "sorted" but without any alteration of the original order.

Is there a way to achieve this ? My goal is to obtain these row as a result after the .loc :

|  | id | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (2022, 'may', 29) | LB46 | 10 | 12 |
| (2022, 'may', 30) | LB46 | 10 | 12 |
| (2022, 'may', 31) | LB46 | 40 | 12 |
| (2022, 'june', 1) | LB46 | 50 | 12 |

An alternative solution I would try is to get the (first) index of the row (2022, 'may', 29), the (last) index of the row (2022, 'june', 1) and then to do an iloc.

Comment: from what i know about pandas, multi index is represented in 3 columns, it would appear to me from the layout and the error that you actually only have 1 index column with 3 things in it which is why you can't sort it properly. You  should split the column into 3 and then thry it again, it should work with the .loc that you did.

Comment: My multi index is well splited in 3 "columns".  It's the pandas to_markdown() which grouping the index columns. I will add the head() for more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem as follow  :

First convert the indexes type (it was not explicitly described but my example include several index types and as it's not know by advance it could be an issue) :

```
        if df is not None:
        if df.index.nlevels > 1:
            df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
                pd.DataFrame(index=df.index).reset_index().astype(str)
            )
        else:
            df.index = df.index.astype(str)
```

Then it's possible to do an iloc as followed to get the expected result:

```
        df = df.iloc[
        df.index.get_loc(('2022','may','29':) : df.index.get_loc('2022','june','01')
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try set the index level 1 as ordered category type

```py
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
t = CategoricalDtype(categories=['may', 'june'], ordered=True)
df.index = df.index.set_levels(df.index.levels[1].astype(t), level=1)

df = df.sort_index()

out = df.loc[(2022,'may',29) : (2022, 'june', 1)]
```

```
print(out)

                id  col1  col2
2022 may  29  LB46    10    12
          30  LB46    10    12
          31  LB46    40    12
     june 1   LB46    50    12
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately I can't manually set the order because I don't know it by advance (it not necessary month or year). The only order on which I can rely is the .csv file I have so the data frame original order.

But you get good element as inside the .loc I had wrong type.
I manage to solve my problem using get_loc and iloc, I will post my solution but it's maybe not ideal.